# REST Get Form Parameters in MessageBodyReader

Tags: forms, rest, post, parameters

I am using REST and trying to figure out if it is possible somehow to get the form parameters in the MessageBodyReader. I have no problems to get a JSONObject from inputstream but I dont know how to do with Form parameters posted with POST method.